# Is there a simple way to "unpack" a list in Neo4j?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a string attribute in my Neo4j database that is actually a list cast as string (e.g. "[1,1,3,10]"). I realize I can alter the load program to make those separate fields (e.g. elem1 = 1, elem2 = 1, elem3 = 3, elem4 = 10) but I want to be able to recast the ones already loaded.

I could write a python but hoping that someone has a "in cypher" way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest to use the apoc library for that.
Depending on what you would like as an outcome:

A collection

```
WITH "[1,1,3,10]" AS string
UNWIND apoc.convert.fromJsonList(string) AS elements
RETURN elements
```

or a map

```
WITH "[1,1,3,10]" AS string
WITH apoc.convert.fromJsonList(string) AS collection
RETURN apoc.map.fromPairs(
         REDUCE(arr=[],i IN collection | 
                arr
                +[['elem'+toString(size(arr)),i]]
         )
     ) AS map
```

Comment: The update worked nicely. Thats elegant. I didn't realize you could reference the elements that way ! Thank you